# Replacing program crashing

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm having a problem with this code, it's supposed to go through all shapes in all slides and replace them but it just crashes at a certain point. First it tells you to insert the word you want to search and then the word that you want it to be replaced with. Once you insert that, it crashes, sometimes going through a few words replacing them and others not. Does anyone know what the problem is? The code is the following:

```
Sub Reemplazar()
Dim sld As Slide
Dim shp As Shape
Dim ShpTxt As TextRange
Dim TmpTxt As TextRange
Dim Findword As String
Dim ReplaceWord As String
Findword = InputBox("Ingrese palabra que se quiere reemplazar")
ReplaceWord = InputBox("Ingrese palabra por la que se va a reemplazar")
  For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides
    For Each shp In sld.Shapes
        Set ShpTxt = shp.TextFrame.TextRange
        If ShpTxt <> "" Then
            Set ShpTxt = shp.TextFrame.TextRange
            Set TmpTxt = ShpTxt.Replace( _
            FindWhat:=Findword, _
            Replacewhat:=ReplaceWord, _
            WholeWords:=False)
            Do While Not TmpTxt Is Nothing
              Set ShpTxt = ShpTxt.Characters(TmpTxt.Start + TmpTxt.Length, ShpTxt.Length)
              Set TmpTxt = ShpTxt.Replace( _
              FindWhat:=Findword, _
              Replacewhat:=ReplaceWord, _
              WholeWords:=False)
            Loop
        End If
    Next shp
  Next sld
End Sub
```

The program stops and asks for debug, giving the message "Error '-2147024809 (80070057)' and highlighting the "Set ShpTxt = shp.TextFrame.TextRange" line

Comment: What does "Crash" mean. Does it hit a point where it gives you an error and asks if you want to debug, or does your powerpoint application actually crash without warning?

Comment: It stops and asks for debug, giving the message "Error '-2147024809 (80070057)' and highlights this line "Set ShpTxt = shp.TextFrame.TextRange"

Comment: Does it give more information than that about the error? It seems to be thrown when the shape is locked/protected or the sheet (in the case of excel, not sure about powerpoint and protection) is protected.

Comment: Other than the error number and "The specified value is out of range", no other info

Comment: So it could be that you've hit a shape that lacks a textframe, which is totally reasonable as not all shapes have them (and things you might not realize are shaped in your powerpoint, are in fact shapes). While it's usually best not to, in this case I think it's perfectly reasonable, before you start looping, to set `On Error Resume Next` and let this thing fly. There's other more complex ways around this, but in this case I probably wouldn't bother.

Comment: It worked perfectly, thank you so much!

Comment: I'm glad that got you through the error. One thing I was unaware of was the `HasTextFrame` method of the powerpoint shape object (there is not, that I'm aware of, a similar method in Excel which I generally use). Please consider using @SteveRindsberg solution below since `On Error Resume Next` can mask other errors. Again, I think `On Error Resume Next` is an OK solution in this case, but if this were my code, I would definitely use that `HasTextFrame` method instead as it's much cleaner.

Comment: @JNevill Totally agree. Excel doesn't seem to have several of the shape methods/properties that PPT does, so I suspect you'd have to rely on error trapping to do the same thing in Excel.

Answer (score 4):

Before trying to do the replacements, verify that it's a shape that CAN hold text and if so, that it DOES hold text:

```
If osh.HasTextFrame Then
    If osh.TextFrame.HasText Then
        ' NOW do your replacements
    End If
End If
```